# Error: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I got an error when I'm doing many requests to the database.
When I click many times on my places/buttons on Application the error appearance.
Every thing works fine til the user do many clicks in the applciation.

Any can help me with this error?

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="XXXXXXXXXX1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/threeptdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="YYYYYYUser" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="YYYYYYPass" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="XXXXXXXXXX2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@site.server.net:1111:xxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="XXXXXXXXXXUser" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="XXXXXXXXXXPass" />

            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.wrap_result_sets" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

It is an example of a entity class that I use:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "primes", schema="public")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public final class PrimeEntity extends PlanItemEntity {

    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public PrimeEntity(Long id,
                       String swpId,
                       String name,
                       String status,
                       String version,
                       Long itTarget,
                       Long bizTarget,
                       List<DomainEntity> domains,
                       String description,
                       String itOwner,
                       String bizOwner,
                       ZonedDateTime excelUpdate) {
        super(id, swpId, name, status, version, itOwner, bizOwner);
        this.itTarget = itTarget;
        this.bizTarget = bizTarget;
        this.domains = domains == null ? new LinkedList<>() : domains;
        this.description = description;
        this.excelUpdate = excelUpdate;
    }

    @Column(name = "it_target")
    private Long itTarget;

    @Column(name = "biz_target")
    private Long bizTarget;

    @Column(name="excel_update")
    private ZonedDateTime excelUpdate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "prime", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OrderBy("UPPER (name) ASC")
    private List<DomainEntity> domains = new LinkedList<>();

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;
}
```

Error log:

```
2019-03-15T15:10:51.137+0000] [] [?[1;93mWARN?[0m] [] [?[1;94morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=38 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1552662651137] [levelValue: 900] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 55000

[2019-03-15T15:10:51.138+0000] [] [?[1;91mERROR?[0m] [] [?[1;94morg.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=38 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1552662651138] [levelValue: 1000] This statement has been closed.

[2019-03-15T15:10:51.152+0000] [] [?[1;91mSEVERE?[0m] [] [?[1;94mfish.payara.microprofile.opentracing.jaxrs.JaxrsContainerRequestTracingFilter?[0m] [tid: _ThreadID=38 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1552662651152] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
        at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:135)
        at com.domain.application.user.UserRoleDao.findByItem(UserRoleDao.java:27)
        at com.domain.application.user.UserRoleService.retrieveByItem(UserRoleService.java:38)
        at com.domain.application.productcatalog.ProductCatalogService.setItemOwnership(ProductCatalogService.java:285)
        at com.domain.application.productcatalog.ProductCatalogService.retrieve(ProductCatalogService.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:579)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkClosed(PgStatement.java:694)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.getMaxRows(PgStatement.java:501)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.createResultSet(PgStatement.java:153)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(PgStatement.java:204)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2120)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        ... 74 more
]]
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your code, not in the configuration.

Comment: But everything works fine when the user use normaly the Application. This is happen when you make a lot of clicks.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your code, not in the configuration.

Comment: The fact that it works as long as the user doesn't click too fast tends to show that your configuration is ok.

Comment: Yes, it's make sense. How can I handle with many requests at same time with hibernate persiste? Should I use sessions in Hibernate for each query I will do?

Comment: please, copy-paste stacktrace. there should be some clues

Comment: I put the stacktrace in the question. thanks

Comment: From where are you calling hibernate? Are you using CDI, JSF Backing beans or EJB?

Comment: private EntityManager entityManager;

    public PrimeDao() {this.entityManager = ConnectionUtil.getConnection();}

    public List<PrimeEntity> findAllOrderByName() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from PrimeEntity order by name").getResultList();
    }

I am using CDI .

Answer (score 0):

It seems like related to the asynchronous processing, when trying to do the same thing over and over again; hibernate tracks changes and it's called dirty checking, on our entities and to reduce time needed to compile the query, by default it's including all fields in update query instead of only those changed.

Try to read about @DynamicUpdate and @OptimisticLock annotations.